# Backbone router, page load navigation doesn't happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, router

I'm sure that this is probably something super trivial.

Everything works like a charm except for the router not updating on page load, the route:post event never fires. Everything router related is run on document load.

Any rudimental mistakes I'm making that might cause this?

```
window.Router = new Backbone.Router(obj = {
  routes: {
    '':'home',
    'page/:id':'post'
  }
});

Router.on('route:home', function(value){

    $(window).scrollTop();
});

Router.on('route:post', function(value){

    window.pageHandler.scrollToSectionWithName("#"+value);

});    

Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Backbone history without pushState:

`Backbone.history.start();`

Check Backbone documentation regarding [History-start](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) to get some hints on what could be possible wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add silent

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, silent: false });
```

Comment: When `silent` is not passed as an option, it is treated as being `false`. So doing what you suggest here is not any different from doing what the OP was already doing: `Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});`

Comment: true, sorry. i've set it on true and ran in the same issue. setting it to false fixed it for me.. lol